# Download file from firebase and upload to stripe for id verification

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Im trying to get a id jpeg that i have stored in firebase storage and upload it to stripe in order to allow my customers to verify their identity. However i get several errors and the function stops

```
import * as https from 'https'
    import * as fs from 'fs'
    const stripe = Stripe('sk_test');

    function getidFile(url: string):Promise<any>{
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream("test.jpg");
            https.get(
                url,
                function(response: IncomingMessage){
                    console.log('Response ', response);
                    response.pipe(file);
                    file.on('finish', function() {
                        file.close();
                        resolve(file);
                    });
                }
            ).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }

    function uploadFileToStripe(fileUrl:string,fileType:string,fileName:string):Promise<any>{
        return getidFile(
            fileUrl
        ).then(
            (data:any) => {
                console.log('File as blob ', data);
                const upload: Promise<any> = 
                stripe.files.create(
                    {
                        file: {
                            data: data,
                            name: fileName,
                            type: 'image/jpeg',
                        },
                        purpose: 'identity_document',
                    }
                );
                return upload.then(
                    (document: any) => {
                        console.log('Document upload ', document);
                        return document;
                    }   
                ).catch(
                    (_error: any) => {
                        console.log('Error uploading document ', _error);
                        return _error;
                    }
                )
            }
        ).catch(
            (_error:any) => {
                console.log('Error with response ', _error);
                return _error;
            }
        );
    }
```

Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'test.jpg'
and then my function stops.

Comment: Are you getting an error back from Stripe or from your `getidFile` function?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options):
```Modifying a file rather than replacing it may require a flags mode of r+ rather than the default mode w```. This could be the root of the issue if you are getting the error in here `fs.createWriteStream("test.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use URL. Use admin.storage() to access your file.

```
export const uploadFileToStripe = functions.https.onCall(async(data,context)=>{

  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('xyz.appspot.com');
  const path = require('path');
  const os = require('os');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const fileName = data['fileName'];
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
  await bucket.file(fileName).download({destination:tempFilePath});

  console.log('File created at', tempFilePath);

  return await stripe.files.create({
    purpose: 'identity_document',
    file: {
      data: fs.readFileSync(tempFilePath),
      name: 'fileUploadDoc.png',
      type: 'application/octet-stream',
    },
  });
});
```